Error occurs while using c#'s BinaryFormatters through pythonnet
I'm currently trying to call the c# functions from python and I've got some issues. I'm sorry but please notice that I'm not that familiar with dotnet etc and in some reason I should use dotnet sdk 2.0.9 versions and BinaryFormatter.
First, I've tried some simple codes given as
namespace test_Cs
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public int add(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
    }
  }
}

and
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System;

namespace test_Cs{
  public class Class2{
    public Class2(){
      Console.WriteLine("Saver enabled");
    }
    public void save(string path, Class1 obj){
      Console.WriteLine("save start");
      // BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
      // Console.WriteLine("hello world!");
      // using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)){
      //   b.Serialize(fs, obj);
      Console.WriteLine(obj.add(3,4));
    }
  }
}

To implement those things,
import clr
clr.AddReference('./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/0.test_Cs')
from test_Cs import Class1, Class2

calc = Class1()

print(calc.add(3,4))

saver = Class2()
saver.save('/Users/jeon-yuseong/0.Jeon_lab/1.codespace_for_lab/2.labcode/4.KRISS/9.practice/0.test_Cs/hi.calc',calc)

On the Class2.save, If I use such function, there is no error and get
7
saver enabled
save start
7

On the other hand if I use Class2.save without annotations, I've got
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000d from typeref (expected class 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter' in assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <5ba5f6ad7b1f4d89b2ed01fcd4973f66>:0 

such error.
I've tried pythonnet 2.5, 2.4, 3.0 to see if it occurs because of versions but the trials failed too.
pythonnet : 2.5, 2.4, 3.0
python : 2.7, 3.7, 3.10
dotnet : 2.0.9
mono : 6.12.0.182

Please help me if there is some way to avoid this error.

"Error occurs while using c#'s BinaryFormatters ..."  - no no. That is the error. Don't do that.

This actually reads as if you are having an X-Y-Problem. You are trying to fix a problem that you shouldn't be having in the first place because there is a better (actually working) solution to your initial problem.

BinaryFormatter is "no, just don't" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-migration-guide/ and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/binaryformatter-removed-from-dotnet-9/ ; just about any option that doesn't use BinaryFormatter will be preferable. I just think you should be very clear about that before going too far down this rabbit hole. Also, .NET Core 2 is .... beyond dead; .NET 9 is about to drop - if you're following an old guide, you can probably just use .NET 8 (or .NET 9 in a few weeks) and not much will change
